# Animate view every time an Observed property changes in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the following code, an Image is animated when you tap on it by changing the `@State` property value. What I would like to be able to do is animate the image every time a `@Published` property value changes, this property is located inside an `ObservableObject` and is dynamically changing.

#### Using Local @State property wrappers, works fine.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scaleValue = 1.0
    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = true
        
    var body: some View {
        
        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            .scaleEffect(scaleValue)
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3), value: isAnimating)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.isAnimating.toggle()
                self.scaleValue = 1.5
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.3){
                    self.scaleValue = 1.0
                }
            }
    }
}
```

#### Using Observed @Published property wrappers, not working. Not sure where to place the animation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scaleValue = 1.0       
    @StateObject private var contentVM = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            .scaleEffect(scaleValue)
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3), value: contentVM.isAnimating)
           // not sure where to add the animation

    }
}
```

#### EDIT: Here is the Working Solution:

Thanks to @Fogmeister and @burnsi

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject{
     @Published var isAnimatingImage = false 
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @StateObject private var contentVM = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {

        @State private var scaleValue = 1.0
        
        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            .scaleEffect(scaleValue)
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3), value: scaleValue)
            .onChange(of: contentVM.isAnimatingImage) {newValue in
                animateImage()
            }
    }

    func animateImage(){
        scaleValue = 1.5
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.3){
            scaleValue = 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `.onChange(of: $property) { // animate }`

Comment: The `.onChange` modifier did the trick, `.onChange(of: contentVM. isAnimating) { animateImage()}`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue here is the wrong usage of the `.animation` modifier.

You don´t need to trigger the animation with a different boolean value. If the animation is "driven" by changing a value, in this case `scaleValue`, use that value in the modifier.

Take a look at your animation in your first example. It doesn´t complete. It scales to the desired size and then shrinks. But it jumps in the middle of the animation while shrinking back.

This would be a proper implementation in your first example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scaleValue = 1.0
        
    var body: some View {
        
        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            .scaleEffect(scaleValue)
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3), value: scaleValue)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.scaleValue = 1.5
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.3){
                    self.scaleValue = 1.0
                }
            }
    }
}
```

and in your second example:

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var scaleValue = 1.0
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @StateObject private var contentVM = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            .scaleEffect(contentVM.scaleValue)
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3), value: contentVM.scaleValue)
            .onTapGesture {
                contentVM.scaleValue = 1.5
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.3){
                    contentVM.scaleValue = 1.0
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue with my first example, makes sense.  The only thing I don't like about controlling the animation with the value from the `ContentViewModel` is the fact that I would need to change the animation scale inside the `ContentViewModel` but it works fine.  `self.scaleValue = 3.5
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.3){
                            self.scaleValue = 1.0 } `.  By the way I don't need the `.onTapGesture` I want the animation to be controlled by the  `ContentViewModel`.

Comment: FYI - I ended up using the `.onChange` modifier as shown in my edited question.

Answer (score 2):

This is why we shouldn't be using view model objects in SwiftUI and this is not what `@StateObject` is designed for - it's designed for when we need a reference type in an `@State` which is not the case here. If you want to group your view data vars together you can put them in a struct, e.g.

```
struct ContentViewConfig {
    var isAnimating = false
    var scaleValue = 1.0

    // mutating func someLogic() {}
}

// then in the View struct:
@State var config = ContentViewConfig()
```